# How to create xamarin android project targeting specific android version?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2019

How to create android project targeting specific android version e.g. v5.0?

it seems when creating new project it is auto picking latest installed target sdk version

it seems they forgot to add those options

[image: visual studio 2019 new project creating window sucks]

Answer (score 0):

This is a part of Android manifest that is available as part of the project properties.

Comment: when I create a project it defaults to latest api version and when I set low version of android from properties window it errors out because it references latest version of dlls

Comment: It is complicated to do that, but the only reason to use old SDK is to bypass some new Google’s rules that are set to api version. Nothing other than that.

Comment: But you may uninstall latest SDK and then the default will work for you...